# Why do I get undefined response from my HTTP request?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, web

My problem is that I get an error in my console:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

**REQUEST CODE:**

```
@Effect()
  bucketsFetch = this.actions$
    .ofType(BucketActions.FETCH_BUCKETS)
    .switchMap(() => {
      console.log('Sending GET request to Server');
      return this.httpClient
        .get<Bucket[]>('/storage/buckets', {
        observe: 'body',
        responseType: 'json'
        });
    })
   .map(
      (buckets) => {
        console.log('Received bucket:' + buckets[0].id);
        return {
          type: BucketActions.SET_BUCKETS,
          payload: buckets
        };
      }
    );
```

The error is throwing at the part where I try to `console.log` my response. The `Bucket` Model is correct 100% and it should return an array of Buckets as per API description, but still I get this error.

I do not know why I get an empty array response from server? Some assumptions are that I am doing something async in a sync way, but not to my awareness / knowledge.

Any ideas?

Comment: `console.log(buckets)`?

Comment: clearly buckets[0] is undefined.

Comment: yes, but this would indicate that I got nothing in response?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I did that now and it shows me an empty array in console. This is weird.. it should return an array of buckets, that is why i am confused.

Comment: Look at the request/response in the dev tools network tab.

Comment: @ChrisFarmer Yes it is empty Array. But now I am left clueless whether it is something wrong in my code... or server does not return OK.

Comment: looks like an asynchronous call being treated as synchronous.

Comment: @epascarello Could be it, but I followed a tutorial for this and it should be asynchronous request using NgRx and HttpClient, which return observable.